# Guids missing in MS Excel when linking to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, excel, guid

When I link an SQL table In MS Access 2007, Guid columns (in Excel) are missing - what am I doin wrong?

Thx!
Mojo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your GUID in SQL is stored in a uniqueidentifier type column? perhaps add a computed column that converts this to a varchar:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_GUID_Test](
    [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [GUID_Str]  AS (CONVERT([varchar](36),[GUID],0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or, create a view / proc / layer that applies the same logic.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Yes guids are stored in uniquidentifier columns. It seams strange that Excel can't handle Guids? Excel could just convert it to string. Maybe there's a switch/setting somewhere?

Comment: @MojoDK Hi Mojo, i'm not sure, i only have access to Excel 2010 at the moment and that can import GUID columns fine (Using MS Query). I'm not aware of any settings that would explain this.

Comment: I've seen Excel lose GUIDs (or not) depending on the transport to a SQL Server  database (named pipes/tcp/shared memory). Locally you get GUIDs, remotely I needed to cast.